# ASP.NET Web Api - Get ActionContext from HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to access the ActionContext in a non-controller class that is called from the controller, in order to access the ActionArguments collection.

I can call HttpContext.Current since it is a Web Api app, however I cannot work out how to access the current ActionContext.

I can always pass the context on to the class from the calling controller, however was interested to see if there is a way this can be done.

I know it is not the best approach.

Comment: You've already answered your question, this is not the best approach, don't do it. Don't make your code rely on the action context, decouple it completely and pass it the data it requires instead.